# Массив активити

Tags: android

Можно ли создать массив активити, что бы потом случайно выбирать и запускать несколько из них? Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4):

Метод [startActivities(Intent[], Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[],%20android.os.Bundle)) запускает массив интентов.

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно:

```
Intent activityArr[] = new Intent[10];
activityArr[0] = new Intent(this, SomeActivity1.class);
activityArr[1] = new Intent(this, SomeActivity2.class);
```

`startActivity(activityArr[0]);`

а вот запускать сразу несколько вряд-ли